# ¿Es "Decimos" y "Décimos" un ejemplo de tilde diacrítica?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, ortografía, acentuación

Me parece que ***decimos*** (*de decir, afirmar*) se escribe **sin** **tilde**, 
mientras que ***décimos*** (*0.2, 0.3, etc.*) se escribe **con** **tilde**.

¿Estoy en lo correcto?

Si lo estoy, me podrían confirmar si esto es un ejemplo de tilde diacrítica o no.

De antemano, ¡Gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: Como dice Luciano no es diacrítica porque la pronunciacion no es igual, la sílaba tónica es diferente en ambos casos: de**CI**mos y **DÉ**cimos.

Answer (score 7):

Efectivamente la conjugación del verbo `decir` no lleva tilde. De todas formas, creo que este no es un ejemplo de tilde diacrítica. La tilde en décimos es ortográfica y responde a la acentuación esdrújula de la misma.

Usualmente la tilde diacrítica aparece en palabras que se escriben y suenan igual para diferenciar distintos significados. En general, se da en monosílabos (aunque hay excepciones) y un buen ejemplo es `si` como la nota musical o la conjunción o `sí` en el caso del adverbio afirmativo.

Saludos!